# LCD USB Touchscreen calibration eGalax

Tags: raspbian, usb, pi-3, hdmi, touchscreen

Ok, I got a Chinese 17" LCD monitor with USB touchcreen. Max resolution is 1280x1024.I use Raspberry 3 Model B with Raspbian OS.

Below are the result from **lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0eef:0001 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax TouchScreen
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 6901:1224  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can touch it, and it respond, but the position is very wrong. The question is how to calibrate it for touchscreen bigger than 7" ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems the answer is in here : 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=78805

And now it works for me :)

Comment: -1 It would be better if you could have outlined a summary of what was needed to be done here.

Answer (score -1):

I have 7" eGalaxtouch screen. Operating system Raspbian Stretch. My way to calibration is demonstrated in video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pChXP9ECa74﻿

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: Although the questioner answered their own question themselves with pretty much a link only answer (which I have just -1 ed) it is not recommended because links can rot and then - with no idea what the solution might have entailed - the answer becomes useless...